# UWP, Playing sound is stop sometime

Tags: audio, uwp

in UWP application, Sometime Playing sound is stop.

```
 await Execute.OnUIThreadAsync(async () =>
 {
    var element = new MediaElement();
    var uri = new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/sound/abc.wav");
    StorageFile sf = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
    var stream = await sf.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    element.SetSource(stream, "");
    element.Play();
 });
```

I think, This UIThread job finish immediately.
but My sound file has 1 minutes length, Then, 
The task was closed. then, Sound can not play by end.

How should I write to play sound ?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following MSDN doc:[Play media in the background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio). To support your music playing in background, you need to check the requirements from "Requirements for background audio". Actually you've mentioned that it is "sometime", so I'm not so sure whether you've already used the solution from the above doc. But if you haven't, you need to refer to that article, enable capbility and then manage both the transitioning and also notice the memory.